Update a many-to-many relation in Supabase?
I'm building a to-do list app with Supabase and Flutter. I have a tasks table, a tags table, and then a tasks_tags table to allow a given task to have multiple tags.
For many-to-many relations, Supabase streamlines SELECTs so you don't have to worry about explicitly querying around the join table. Like, when I select from tasks I get tasks back with a synthesized tags field. Nice.
But the same isn't true for UPDATEs: when updating a task, I actually have to remove the tags field or Supabase will throw an error.
So then the question is, what's the best (and most Supabase-friendly) way to update the tags on a task? That is, let's say pre-UPDATE, a task has tags 123 and 456 on it, and I want to update it so it keeps 456, removes 123, and adds 789. How best to accomplish that without too many separate queries?
Thanks!
